# How to get the input(StyledComponent) value by ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, ref

I am trying to set the ref for a  styled components.

The component has been created with const Input = styled.input. but i can't get value of input by ref.

My code :

```
const _Input = styled.input`
  background-image: linear-gradient(#20aee3, #20aee3), linear-gradient(#bfbfbf, #bfbfbf);
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  float: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: center bottom, center calc(100% - 1px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0 2px, 100% 1px;
  padding: 0;
  transition: background 0s ease-out 0s;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  min-height: 35px;
  display: initial;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  &:focus {
      background-size: 100% 2px, 100% 1px;
      outline: 0 none;
      transition-duration: 0.3s;
      color: #525252;
    }
`;

...
<_Input type='text' ref="name" placeholder="name .."/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

> innerRef="name"

For styled component ref will not work instead you have to use innerRef.

Comment: i received an error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined. when i use componentDidMount() {
    this.input.focus()
  }

Comment: <_Input type='text' id="abc" innerRef={(comp) => { this.input = comp }} placeholder="name"/>

Comment: Use <_Input type='text' id="abc" innerRef={(comp) => { this.input = comp; }} placeholder="name"/>

You forget to use semicolon.

Comment: i still receive 'undefined'

Comment: i fixed error undefined . but how to get value form input

Comment: i can't get value

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I got it.
You can't get ref from styled component. You need to pass some parameter to it and then pass it to as ref to Component which you are using.
You can look up to this link for example: 
https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1151

Comment: but i can't get value in input